# Repairing dual boot using Ubuntu Live CD

Tags: boot, multi-boot, troubleshooting, bootrepair

I installed Windows 7 on a separate hard drive and I have Debian on another hard drive. After installing Windows 7 my grub doesn't appear so I used an Ubuntu Live CD to use boot-repair to fix my grub2 installation. Everything went well but after I restart it boots directly into Windows 7 and no grub shows up.

Like I said I have two hard drives one with Windows 7 (sda) and one with Debian (sdb). I installed grub2 on sdb following the boot-repair process but it doesn't work. Any ideas of what I should do.

Here is my boot info: [paste.ubuntu.com/1492985](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1492985/)

Comment: You seems to have both grub *and* grub2 installed on your Linux. And you linux distro is Debian, why do you want to use Ubuntu Live CD not debian one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the boot loader (grub2) needs to be on the hard drive that boots first. Generally that's sda. As such, you either need to install grub2 on sda, or you need to make sdb boot first.